# Add a product review with ratings programmatically in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, comments, rating

The title says it all.  I know the reviews are the native comments post type in Wordpress.  I have included the code to add a comment.

The problem is however I am unclear how to give the comment a rating and how to tie it to a particular product.  When I use the comment_post_ID it does not seem to be assigning the comment (review) to the correct post.

```
$time = current_time('mysql');

$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID' => 1,
    'comment_author' => 'admin',
    'comment_author_email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'comment_author_url' => 'http://',
    'comment_content' => 'content here',
    'comment_type' => '',
    'comment_parent' => 0,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'comment_author_IP' => '127.0.0.1',
    'comment_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
    'comment_date' => $time,
    'comment_approved' => 1,
);

wp_insert_comment($data);
```

Comment: your code should be fine, did you check if you code inserting comment to database ?as the `comment_post_ID` is the one which associate the comment with any type of posts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the key `'comment_post_ID'` is where your comment will be shown, so desired product ID

Then you can use [`update_comment_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_comment_meta) dedicated WordPress function to add a rating, like:

```
update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', 3 ); // The rating is an integer from 1 to 5
```

So your code will be like *(where* `$product_id` *is the targeted product Id for this review):*

```
$comment_id = wp_insert_comment( array(
    'comment_post_ID'      => 37, // <=== The product ID where the review will show up
    'comment_author'       => 'LoicTheAztec',
    'comment_author_email' => 'loictheaztec@fantastic.com', // <== Important
    'comment_author_url'   => '',
    'comment_content'      => 'content here',
    'comment_type'         => '',
    'comment_parent'       => 0,
    'user_id'              => 5, // <== Important
    'comment_author_IP'    => '',
    'comment_agent'        => '',
    'comment_date'         => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'comment_approved'     => 1,
) );

// HERE inserting the rating (an integer from 1 to 5)
update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', 3 );
```

Tested and works as intended.

> The **author email** and the **user ID** need to be some existing ones.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not complete as the question contains *how to tie it to a particular product*. Also **comment type** should be **populated** as *review*. If the review is not tied to the product, Yoast schema and other dont **populate all variables and Google will give you Warning** about the **schema** markup.

Add this to the accepted answer:

```
'comment_type'          => 'review'
```

Also, tie to the product (your `$post_id`), remark bool values and arrays.

```
if($comment_id) update_comment_meta($comment_id, 'rating', 5);
if($comment_id) update_comment_meta($comment_id, 'verified', 1);
    
if($comment_id) update_post_meta($post_id, '_wc_average_rating', '5.00');
if($comment_id) update_post_meta($post_id, '_wc_review_count', '1');
if($comment_id) update_post_meta($post_id, '_wc_rating_count', array(1));
```

Now Google accept this as a charm as of Woocommerce 3 and year 2020. @loictheastec you can edit yourself if you want.

Comment: Great! Now my plugin works as expected! Product meta was missing. But remember this approach only should be used when the product is created -as the counts otherwise start to missmatch.

Comment: How do you handle this meta data as you add more reviews/ratings?